# Sophisticated FOP examples?

Tags: java, pdf, report, itext, apache-fop

I'm reviewing PDF generation tools available for Java and haven't found much of the examples.

The best for FOP so far was the documentation linked in this [question](http://bsdfeed.com/discussion/comment/17499).

For the iText the best I had found are the Advanced Aquarist magazine [samples](http://www.advancedaquarist.com/pdf/AdvancedAquarist-2008-01.pdf/at_download/file) for 2008.

Unfortunately for both cases there are no sources. As I have some background with iText, the Aquarist seems to be reaching iText's maximum in this sample. Is there anything like this for FOP?

Comment: Strange question. As iText is a library that allows you to create a PDF at the lowest-level using every feature available in ISO-32000-1, it's strange to read that iText has a "maximum". I kind of like this example: https://devoxxguide.googlecode.com/files/conference_29oct.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the example. I'm sorry, I didn't want to say iText is technically incapable of something, it just seems for me it lacks designer-friendly publishing features like CSS. FOP is not much better in this case, however it's markup can be edited by mere mortals. :-)

Comment: There are many XSL FO samples on RenderX web site, some with sources. If you need specific examples of sophisticated documents (like a 401K statement or such), just ask at the web site and I can get them for you.

Comment: Thanks, a very nice set of examples.

Comment: I posted a few others for you based on what you asked. These are all done with a designer and showcase XSL FO formatting, including advanced manipulation of output like bookfolding the results for print. Use http://www.tandesa.com/Public/Samples/Sample1.pdf, http://www.tandesa.com/Public/Samples/Sample2.pdf, http://www.tandesa.com/Public/Samples/Sample3.pdf, http://www.tandesa.com/Public/Samples/Sample4.pdf. They include dynamic charts in SVG as well as custom PDF fillable forms.

Comment: All relevant links are broken, even the ones in the comments.